# Unable to get Ripple session info for port 9222

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, ripple, taco

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with tools for Apache Cordova version 9.

I have an existing project that was working OK but all of a sudden I get

> Unable to get Ripple session info for port 9222. Please close all instances of Chrome and try again.
>   An error occurred trying to attach to the Ripple emulator. Exception: >Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)).

when using the ripple emulator.

Chrome opens, but instead of seeing my index page the address bar just has my IP address and the page shows a 404.

The project builds/rebuilds fine. This also happens if I create a new blank Apache Cordova app.

I have tried:

- deleting .suo and .sln
- run VS as administrator
- clear cordova cache
- clean solution
- reboot PC
- Repair TACO
- reinstall NPM

What else can I try? Is it just me or is TACO  this flaky for everyone?

Comment: Try reinstall chrome browser,if it doesn't work, try reinstall tools for apache cordova.

Comment: Neither reinstalling Chrome nor reinstalling TACO helped.

Comment: Try changing to a different port by specifying it in Visual Studio-> Tools-> Options-> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Ripple Emulator. Try changing back to default one 4400 or different port.

Comment: yay ! Thank Alan - choosing a different port did the trick. Martin

Answer (score 1):

1) Right-click solution in project explorer, click Debug => Start new instance.

2) Go to Project => Properties => Configuration Manager, in top left corner click 'deploy'.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand:
Do you mean right click the project in Solution Explorer ? That is the only place I could find "Debug, Start new Instance". When I do this i get the same error.
If I open Configuration Manager, Deploy (in the right hand corner for me) is already ticked. Did you mean un-tick it ?